# How to use malloc and free for Dynamic Memory Allocation

Tags: c, malloc

I just started learning C, coming from php. I don't understand yet how to use malloc and free.

**1) In the example code below, where I can put "free"?**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int strLen(char* text) {
  int c = 0;
  for (int i = 0; text[i] != '\0'; ++i) ++c;
  return c;
}


char* reverse(char* text) {

  int count = strLen(text);
  char* t = malloc(count);

  for (int i = count; i > 0; --i) { t[count - i] = text[i-1]; }
  t[count] = '\0'; /* Add end of string */

  return t;

}


int main (int argc, char** argv) {

  if (argc > 1) {
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) { 
      printf("%d\t%s\t%s\n", i, argv[i], reverse(argv[i])); 
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**2) This is the output from valgrind. What mean the errors "Invalid write of size 1" and "Invalid read of size 1"?**

```
valgrind ./reverse Text ONe
==3124== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3124== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3124== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3124== Command: ./reverse Text ONe
==3124==
==3124== Invalid write of size 1
==3124==    at 0x40060F: reverse (in /localServer/temp/C/reverse)
==3124==    by 0x400654: main (in /localServer/temp/C/reverse)
==3124==  Address 0x5203044 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==3124==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3124==    by 0x4005C6: reverse (in /localServer/temp/C/reverse)
==3124==    by 0x400654: main (in /localServer/temp/C/reverse)
==3124==
==3124== Invalid read of size 1
==3124==    at 0x4E88CC0: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1632)
==3124==    by 0x4E8F898: printf (printf.c:33)
==3124==    by 0x400682: main (in /localServer/temp/C/reverse)
==3124==  Address 0x5203044 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==3124==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3124==    by 0x4005C6: reverse (in /localServer/temp/C/reverse)
==3124==    by 0x400654: main (in /localServer/temp/C/reverse)
==3124==
1 Text  txeT
2 ONe eNO
==3124==
==3124== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3124==     in use at exit: 7 bytes in 2 blocks
==3124==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 1 frees, 1,031 bytes allocated
==3124==
==3124== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3124==    definitely lost: 7 bytes in 2 blocks
==3124==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3124==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3124==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3124==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3124== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==3124==
==3124== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3124== ERROR SUMMARY: 4 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put free in the loop, after your usage of the pointer returned by reverse, as follows.

```
int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    char *reverseStrPtr;

    if (argc > 1) {
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
            reverseStrPtr = reverse(argv[i]);
            printf("%d\t%s\t%s\n", i, argv[i], reverseStrPtr); 
            free(reverseStrPtr);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Also, the valgrind error is based on the line below which is in `reverse`.

```
t[count] = '\0'; /* Add end of string */
```

Simply put, when you allocate count-many bytes, your index range is `[0, count)`. So trying to access count is equivalent to accessing `(count+1)`th bit, and that is an access violation.

What you need to correct is the amount of memory you allocate, which is `(count+1)` bytes. The extra byte is needed to place the terminating `'\0'` character.

```
char* reverse(char* text) {
    int count = strLen(text);
    char* t = malloc(count+1); // +1 for the terminating '\0'

    for (int i = count; i > 0; --i) { t[count - i] = text[i-1];}
    t[count] = '\0'; /* Add end of string */

    return t;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to retain the pointer returned back from `reverse(argv[i])`, and `free` it.

One way is to adjust `main` slightly to

```
int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    char* s;

    // if (argc > 1) { Comment out the redundant check
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) { 
            printf("%d\t%s\t%s\n", i, argv[i], s = reverse(argv[i]));
            free(s); 
        }
    //}
    return 0;
}
```

Assignments deep within expressions are not to everyone's taste (as they can obfuscate), but they work well in instances like this. I'm of the ilk that you should get used to things like this in C.

Also, `t[count] = '\0';` overruns your buffer - the behaviour of that is *undefined*. You need `malloc(1 + count);`